# Term weighting for original LDA in gensim

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling, gensim

I am using the gensim library to apply LDA to a set of documents. Using gensim I can apply LDA to a corpus  whatever the term weights are: binary, tf, tf-idf...

My question is, what is the term weighting that should be used for the original [LDA](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf)? If I have understood correctly the weights should be term frequencies, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a corpus represented as a "bag of words". Or, yes, lists of term counts.

The correct format is that of the `corpus` defined in the [first tutorial on the Gensim webpage](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html) (these are really useful).

Namely, if you have a `dictionary` as defined in Radim's tutorial, and the following documents,

```
doc1 = ['big', 'data', 'technique', 'lots', 'of', 'cash']
doc2 = ['this', 'document', 'has', 'words']
docs = [doc1, doc2]
```

then your corpus (for use with LDA) should be an iterable object (such as a list) of lists of tuples of the form:  `(dictKey, count)`, where `dk` refers to the dictionary key of a term, and count is the number of times it occurs in the document. This is done for you with

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]
```

That `doc2bow` function means "document to bag of words".